# Cannot open <MyService> service on computer '.'

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a website created by C# which is to start a services in a server.

I created a services called `MyService` using this :

```
instsrv MyService %systemroot%\system32\srvany.exe
```

then I uses the following code to call it :

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("MyService");
try
{
    service.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

but when I access the website and trigger this event, it prompt me

`Cannot open <MyService> service on computer '.'`

Is it because of the security or permission problem?? Any guide with clear steps is highly appreciated.

Comment: under which identity does your web application works? by default, it's NETWORK SERVICE... which won't have rights to start/stop service

Comment: @steve : sorry for my doubt, what do you mean which identity?? if it is web service. Is there any other way to solve this?? i try adding NETWORK SERVICE as Administrator group. I try on the Services>Properties>Log On>Log On as NETWORK SERVICE. It does not seems to solve it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have actually solve the problem of on top scenario.

- The service in this case is "MyService" need to set the log on to Local System Account and check Allow service to interact with desktop
- In the IIS Manager, create a Application Pool for the particular website. And load the website in to it.
- The particular Application Pool **Identitys** need to predefined to **Local Syatem**

This is what is needed in the IIS and services.msc

On the other hand, there will still be errors about the MAC address.
So, we need a  which can be generate by [machineKey Generator](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey). 
The machineKey generated is needed to paste at the  tag below.

Then copy the whole block of the quote below and paste it to the `Web.config`

```
<pages buffer="false"
enableViewState="false"
enableSessionState="false"
enableViewStateMac="false"
validateRequest="false"
enableEventValidation="false"
viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never"/>

<machineKey 
validationKey="8FCCB821044C5174C551129400F278B5629C64EAC195046DA5FE608EF418913C1139636E13FE  9F8C35AD3C10C394CAC1D9CEBB8B6BDA018165E91136B1AADBE1"
decryptionKey="3F260119F4CC0A0DD8C6B4979C70644A0ED2DD19B3ADB00F85FB7C83634FC544"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"
/>
```

And the problem will then be solved, maybe the situation you guys faced may be different but I hope it may help someone as I struggle in this quite a long time.

In addition, I uses this code so there will no conflict when start and stop the services created.

```
if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
{
    try
    {
        service.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
else
{
    try
    {
        service.Stop();
        service.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Good Luck and thank you guys for helping.

ref:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/ 
http://forums.asp.net/t/906759.aspx/3/10

Answer (score 2):

with iis (version 6 and higher), web apps are run using an application pool. EAch application pool can run with a specific user (the identity), which is, by default, NETWORK SERVICE. It's a very bad idea to add this user to local administrators.

Possible ways :

- Grants the necessary privilege to start/stop the service to this user, setup an dedicated application pool to use this identity and ensure the account have read access to the asp/.net application path.
- create a dedicated account too. within you application, connect to the service management using a username/password you store securely in the config (crypt the section). I'm not sure if you can specify a user/password with service control, but you can at least, use WMI or Process.Start with a net stop / net start command.

Comment: A very what idea? Good or bad?

Answer (score 1):

hi i had the same prob been giving permission to all group that i thought of include the cleaners and it didnt help finally i tried this line in my web config

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="Domainname\admin" password="123" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help someone with a related issue:

On my server, a powershell commandlet was failing with the same error message.
It was because, even if I was logged as the local admin, I needed to run the PowerShell environment as an administrator (right click, run as Administrator).