# Invoke windows service from asp.net web app on iis

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I want to start a windows service from asp.net webform which are deployed on the server . It gives error cannot control  service on this computer

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the impersonation to control your windows service from asp.net application. To access the windows service from web application required some access rights on machine where you have installed the service.

[Please check this link it may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453447/cannot-open-myservice-service-on-computer)

Comment: @HamzaaAsif, No body asked you to accept or up vote the answer and I don't even need your vote. You have posted the question hence I given you the relative answer .. don't try to act over smart.